# Disable webpages asking for location?

Tags: safari, geolocation

I've got a webpage that I have to access for work each morning and it continually asks to use my location. Is there an way to block this from asking for my location? I'm not so much concerned about it knowing my location as I am tired of the Safari drop down alert asking for it over and over and over again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safari > Prefs > Privacy > Website use of Location services:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That's one headache I don't have to deal with anymore! :)